# Java: BufferedReader and NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

My code works as supposed, the a problem arises when I type in this `if` statement:

```
if (sList.get(i).equals(null)){break;}
```

the program crashes with the following debug information (NullPointerException):

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at HangmanLexicon.(HangmanLexicon.java:51)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>       at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:807)
>       at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
>       at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Here is all the code (yeah I know it´s messy, it looks that way when learning new stuff):

```
public HangmanLexicon() 
{
/* 1. Open the data file HangmanLexicon.txt using a 
 * BufferedReader that will allow you to read it line by line. */
String readWord = "";


 try
 {
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("ShorterLexicon.txt"));

    while (true)
    {
        readWord = rd.readLine();
        println(readWord);
        sList.add(readWord);
        if (readWord == null){
            println("Shit has hit the fan.");
            break;}
    }
    rd.close();
 }
 catch (IOException ex)
 {
     println ("Shit has hit the fan.");
     throw new ErrorException(ex);
 }

 println("readWord: "+ readWord);
/* 2. Read the lines from the file into an ArrayList. */
 for (int i = 0; i < sList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sList.get(i).equals (null)){println("done.");}
        println("get: "+sList.get(i) + " pos: " + i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `sList.get(i)` is `null` and you are calling `equals()` operation on `null` which results in `NullPointerException`.

Use

```
if (sList.get(i)== null)
```

instead of

```
if (sList.get(i).equals (null))
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't test for `null` this way, instead use:

```
if (sList.get(i) == null)
```

Your usage of `equals` has a problem in that a `NullPointerException` will naturally occur if the result of the `get` is `null`: because you can't call a method on `null`.

Answer (score 2):

when you have a `null` value in your array, you can not call `equal` function, simply compare with null

```
if(sList.get(i) == null){
    println("done.");
}else{
    println("get: "+sList.get(i) + " pos: " + i);
}
```

i suggesting you to use function `ready` of class `BufferedReader` in `while` loop

```
while(rd.ready()){
   // read 
}
```

see [ready()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The bufferedReader store the value of String as "null" and not null if br.readLine() is empty

So try checking

```
(!Stringval.equalisIgnoreCase("null"))
```

instead of

```
(Stringval != null) or (Stringval.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
```